# How to reset a lost mysql root password

Tags: mysql, passwords, digital-ocean

I have done some research in how to reset a mySQL root password but when I try to run this command:

```
sudo stop mysql
```

and it outputs: `stop unknown instance`

Then I try and run:

```
# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

I get: `A mysqld process already exists`

Update:

Tried the other way that is suggested and ran into this error:
[image]

Comment: Try `sudo kill -3 mysqld` and then try starting again and see if it works.

Comment: Regardless of my answer below, it seems like your `stop` execution is incorrect, and should probably be `sudo service mysql stop`. But do take a look at the different methods for recovering the root password.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

or

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Answer (score 1):

Improving on your research: to reset a root password, may I suggest that you do *not* use `--skip-grant-tables`. This advice is so common but mostly pointless and dangerous; it requires two restarts of your server. Please see my post [Dangers of skip-grant-tables](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/dangers-of-skip-grant-tables).

An easier solution is to use the `init-file` configuration variable, and point it to a file where you `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('123456')` as explained in the above post.

There are further hacks which actually allow you to change the password without downtime, and those can be found in comments to this blog post: [Recovering a MySQL root password: the fourth solution](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/recovering-a-mysql-root-password-the-fourth-solution)

With regard the fact you are unable to start MySQL, follow similar advice of @drew010 's comment by `killall -TERM mysqld` or `killall -9 mysqld` if the former does not do the trick. You may also take a look at the error log (typically `/var/log/mysqld.log` but otherwise as configured in your `my.cnf` settings file).

Comment: SO trying the other way and still running into issues. Image posted in update to above post.

Answer (score 0):

I am not having a big exposure on how to reset mysql root password, but according to the question and error `A mysqld process already exists` it means some other instance or process might have started the stopped service.

According to [Recover MySQL root password](https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-changing-resetting-mysql-root-passwords) the command which is used to stop the My Sql Service is

> /etc/init.d/mysql stop

So try that command, and try to follow the steps and if you get the same error again then after stopping the My Sql service, just run this command to see which process are still running 
`ps -ef | grep 'mysql'`
Output will look like

> mysql     2370     1  0 Dec04 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr
>   mysql     2504  2370  0 Dec04 ?        00:25:22 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/lib64/mysql/plugin --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql 
> /mysql.sock
>   root     38107 22476  0 08:54 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql

And try to manually kill the process with `kill - 9 pid`